# Can someone solve this in order to provide an example for solving central force problems?

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

Let $F(x)=x$ be a function that describes the magnitude and direction of a force that varies with distance from the origin. I understand that $m \frac {d^2} {dt^2} p(t) = F(p(t))$ is used to derive the motion of a point particle $P$ placed within this force field, but could someone please show me how to do this for this simple case? I just need an example of how to do this before I move on to more complex fields.

Answer (score 2):

Well firstly $p$ might not be the best letter for the position of a particle since $p$ is commonly used for linear momentum and is used in Newtons laws, $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$.

Anyway, suppose a particle whose position I will denote $x(t)$ feels a force directly proportional to it's displacement from the origin of our co-ordinate system $0$, is given by $F(x)=x$, then it's motion is given by solving the resultant differential equation:

$$x=F(x)=\frac{dp}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dt}=m\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$$

We'll firstly take this as a $1d$ equation for simplicity.

If $F(x)=-x$ it would be a restoring force like a spring, however, this force pushes away from the origin, and the force is bigger the further you are away.

$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{m}x(t) \text{ is solved by } x(t)=Ae^{\,t/m^{1/2}}+Be^{-t/m^{1/2}}$$

This can be solved either by checking, or in principle by power series or some method for constant coefficient odes. Note mass $m$ is a positive quantity so there's no problem with square roots.

Now to solve this fully we need initial conditions. You could specify $x(t_1)=x_1$ and $x(t_2)=x_2$ which would be Dirichilet conditions, $v(t_1)=v_1$ and $v(t_2)=v_2$, which would be Neumann, or mixed or so on.

Either way we need two conditions to fully specify the motion, and solve for the two undetermined constants $A$ and $B$.

If you would like to analyse motions, consider the energy of the system, $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+U(x)$, take $U(0)=0$ and $U(x)=-\int_0^x x' dx'=-x^2/2$, so the energy $E=-2AB$, check by $v(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and sub in.

[image: U(x)]

As an over view of the motions, if the energy $E=0$, see green line, the particle can exist and stay at the origin iff $A=B=0$, i.e., it starts there and has no velocity. This is an unstable equilibrium point. If it does not have a velocity $=0$ at $x=0$ it will move off to infinity in the direction it crosses $0$.

Otherwise regardless of where else the particle starts it will feel a force away from the origin, and will move off to either $\pm \infty$. See the red curve. If it moves in from the left, it slows down and stops where it meets the red line, then turns and moves back to $-\infty$, or if it approaches from the right of $0$, it again slows and stops at the red line and moves away to $+\infty$.

A final remark on more than one dimension.

$\vec{x}=\vec{F}=m\frac{d^2\vec{x}}{dt^2}$ is *three* in three dimensions. You can solve each component separately, and try a similar analysis in that case.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand this step: $ \frac {d^2 x}{dt^2} = \frac {1}{m} x(t)$ is solved by  $x(t) = Ae^{(\frac {t}{\sqrt m})} + Be^{-(\frac{t}{\sqrt m})}$ Where did the equation involving A and B come from?

Comment: @J_Psi So there's a few ways to arrive at the answer. The first thing to know is that a second order equation has two independent solutions in this case $e^{+t/m^{1/2}}$ and $e^{-t/m^{1/2}}$, and so you can add them together with constants. This is because the ode is *linear*. As to arriving at each solution there's various ways. First supposing you knew that $\frac{d}{dt}e^{\pm at}=\pm ae^{\pm at}$ from calculus, then taking a second derivative $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}e^{\pm at}=+a^2e^{\pm at}$. So comparing with what we wanted we take $a^2=\frac1m$.

Comment: @J_Psi another way which generalises to other linear odes is to expand $x(t)=\sum_n a_n t^n$ as a Taylor series and sub into the differential equation. You then collect orders of $t$ together by combing the sum. This ends up giving you a recurrence relation to solve for $a_n$, which should be something like $a_{n+2}/a_n=(1/m)(\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)}$. Which should give that $a_n=\frac{(\pm 1/m^{1/2})^n}{n!}$ which then you'd have to recognise is the Taylor series for the exponential function. This method is a bit more complicated I suppose those.

Comment: @J_Psi Maybe what you're looking for also is this. Supposing I write a random force down, there's no guarantee I can solve newtons equations with this force in terms of elementary functions like $\sin t$, $\cos t$, $e^t$, and combinations thereof. I believe if you even take $F(x)=x^2$ then the equation $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{1}{m}x^2$ is one of these examples. I think the solutions are elliptic functions and you'd probably have to numerically solve them to get an idea what they look like, or be comfortable with elliptic functions. However $\ldots$

Comment: @J_Psi what you can do is write down a potential $U(x)$ with the same method as above and look at the motion of the particle given a certain energy, and because the graph of the potential is pretty straightforward you can get a good idea of how it moves, when it speeds up slows down, turns around etc.

Comment: I also apologise for very long comments!